# Creating circle on the every edge of rectangle

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want to create on the edge of every side of the rectangle a small circle instead of only corner.
I make a label that set :

```
 exampleLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2.0

exampleLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

[image: enter image descriptiond here]

So to get something like this shape :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also draw in each corner a circle.

```
    let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -2.5, y: -2.5, width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
    circle.layer.cornerRadius = 2.5
    circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    self.exampleLabel.addSubview(circle)
```

this is a circle in the left top corner. You can do it also for left bottom/right top/ right bottom.

You can play with the position by the x and y value

Let me know if this is what you want

Comment: yes , thank u : ) I will do the same for the other 3 edges :P

Comment: Good job! @RosS